# Making select option with two options?

Tags: php, html

**I have a main-categories and sub-categories:**

```
Category: applications
Subcategory: windows
Category: applications
Subcategory: linux
Category: movies
Subcategory: xvid
```

**Here's my `<select>`:**

```
<select name="category">
    <optgroup label="APPLICATIONS">
        <option value="applications[windows]">Windows</option>
        <option value="applications[Linux]">Linux</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="MOVIES">
        <option value="movies[xvid]">Xvid</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Is there a good way for PHP to recognize which is the main-category and sub-category after the form submit?**

The other way I think about is: `applications_windows` and then explode the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array(
    'applications' => array(
        'windows', 'linux'
    ),
    'movies' => array(
        'xvid'
    )
);

$select = '<select name="category">';
foreach($data as $catName => $catData){
    $select .= '<optgroup label="'.$catName.'">';
    foreach($catData as $item){
        $select .= '<option value="'.$catName.'['.$item.']">'.$item.'</option>';
    }
    $select .= '</optgroup>';
}
$select .= '</select>';

echo $select;
```

This will return this:

[image: This will return this].

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have confused you, the actual question is in the end of my post, I've updated it now.

Comment: Well, when you submit the form, use ```print_r($_POST['category'])``` and you'll see something like ```[category=>array('applications'=>'windows')]```. Is that what you want, right? Note that you're using all items in the same select, sou if isn't a multiselect, you'll onlye get one value.

Comment: That's the problem, I see this: Array ( [category] => applications[windows] ), but I want to see it as array...

Comment: That way you're trying to, I can't realize any solution. But, if you want to use as array, you can use something [like this](http://pastebin.com/YEejqL1r). [Your result will be this](http://prntscr.com/5ml72g)

Comment: Hmm no, this won't work in my case... I'm thinking about making AJAX selection of the categories (first selecting the main, then the sub)...